# Knuth List Insertion Method in C

Tags: c, insertion-sort, knuth, taocp

I've been reading through the sorting and searching algorithms in Volume 3 of The Art of Computer Programming by Donald Knuth, Second Edition.  I came across an algorithm which Knuth calls "list insertion" (A modification on traditional insertion sort) on page 95.

On that page, Knuth concludes that the "right data structure for straight insertion is a one-way, linked linear list.", and that "linked allocation (Section 2.2.3) is ideally suited to insertion, since only a few links need to be changed."  However, the MIXAL program (Program L) on page 97 does not appear to utilize a traditional linked linear list structure (a series of nodes linked by addresses). Instead, it appears that the key and the link are stored together in a struct-like structure and these structures are stored in an array called `INPUT`.

I decided to try to implement this algorithm in C.  I have provided Knuth's description of the algorithm, and his implementation in the MIXAL assembly language as reference.  I decided to let the keys be the elements, themselves, in the `data` array, and I put the links in a parallel-like array called `links`.  I say 'parallel-like array' because the size of the `links` array is one greater than the size of the `data` array. I did this so I could easily determine the index of the smallest element of the `data` array by storing it as the first element in the `links` array.  Because of this extra index in `links`, the indices 0 - (n - 1) of the `data` array correspond to indices 1 - n of the `links` array.  Each element in the `links` array corresponds to the index in the `data` array of the next element in the sorted list.

My question is, is this how this algorithm is supposed to be implemented based on his description, or am I missing something?

[image: list insertion description]

[image: list insertion MIXAL implementation]

```
int *listInsertion(int data[], int n) {

    if (n > 1) {
        int i, j, entry;
        int *links = (int *) calloc(n + 1, sizeof *links);
        links[n] = -1;
        links[n - 1] = n - 1;

        for (i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
            entry = data[i];
            for (j = i + 1; links[j] >= 0 && entry > data[links[j]]; 
                    j = links[j] + 1)
                continue;

            if (j == i + 1) {
                links[i] = i;
            } else {
                links[i] = links[i + 1];
                links[i + 1] = links[j];
                links[j] = i;
            }
        }
        return links;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't line `09` of the MIXAL code be `LDA INPUT,1(KEY)` ?

Comment: For others reading this, K and L share the same address space. K is stored in (0:3), which is the sign bit and the upper 3 bytes of memory words. L is stored in (4:5), which is the lower 2 bytes of memory words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you implement the algorithm with the symbol mentioned by Knuth first.
This will help you figure out the first version quickly.

```
void insertSort(const int *K, int *L, int n) {
  if (n == 1) return;

  L[n] = n-1; 
  L[n-1] = n;

  for (int j = n-2; j >= 0; j--) {
    int entry = K[j];
    int p = L[n];
    int q = n;

    while(entry > K[p]) {
      q = p;
      p = L[q];
      if (p == n) {
        break;
      }
    }

    L[q] = j;
    L[j] = p;
  }
}
```

Then you can refactor your first version to enhance it or make it shorter.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Yours is closer to the MIX assembly code that Knuth describes.  Thank you.  So, he is not describing a linked list in the traditional sense?  That is, the links don't refer to actual addresses in memory, but to array indices?

Comment: @BlaqICE Well, the array index is actually the memory address offset. So in my code, the 'L'(links) is a linked list which is represented by an array. You can try to refactor it to a linked list which is linked by pointers.